# How i can echo only the header that i want? php

Tags: php, header

So i want to echo only a header not all of them.

An example the Server header which contains the information what server it is.

Or X-powered: PHP/version header.

I know i can use print_r($headers["0"]); but the problem here is  i will don't know what number is that header exactly.

```
Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden [1] => Date: Fri, 26 Jun 2020 21:44:53 GMT [2] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 [3] => Connection: close [4] => CF-Chl-Bypass: 1 [5] => Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d3cb45768070a21a77835f417592827541593207893; expires=Sun, 26-Jul-20 21:44:53 GMT; path=/; domain=.onetap.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax...................
```

how i can print only the header i want without knowing the array number.

```
$url = "https://www.google.com/";
$headers = get_header($url);

print_r($headers["0"]);
```

Comment: Iterate and search for a required substring. If string found - output.

Comment: The thing here is i want to get the content inside the header.

Comment: An example i want to know the php version if i echo that header.

Comment: If i would try 
if (in_array("X-Powered: PHP/version", $headers)) {
    //do smth
} That would require more resources and it dont want to do that.

Comment: [edit] your question, add code there.

Comment: What resources are you talking about? another microsecond or two?

Comment: There are a lot of php versions including the fixes and things. and i don't think you would have a good time copying them and pasting them in a if(in_array and it requires more time to do it. i just asked if there is a thing to print that specified header. https://www.php.net/releases/index.php

Comment: Check for substring with `strpos`. Then extract value of version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over your `$headers` and search for a substring in every header:

```
$headers = get_headers($url);
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    if (false !== strpos($header, 'X-powered:')) {
        echo $header;
        // now extract required value, e.g:
        $data = explode('/', $header);
        echo 'Version is: ' . $data[1];
        
        // use break to stop further looping
        break;
    }
}
```

Using second parameter of `get_headers` as 1, will even give you an array, so you can check if required key exists with `isset` or `array_key_exists`:

```
$headers = get_headers($url);
if (isset($headers['X-powered'])) {
    echo $headers['X-powered'];
    // now extract required value, e.g:
    $data = explode('/', $headers['X-powered']);
    echo 'Version is: ' . $data[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use second parameter

```
print_r(get_headers($url, 1));

Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [Date] => Sat, 29 May 2004 12:28:14 GMT
    [Server] => Apache/1.3.27 (Unix)  (Red-Hat/Linux)
    [Last-Modified] => Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
    [ETag] => "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
    [Accept-Ranges] => bytes
    [Content-Length] => 438
    [Connection] => close
    [Content-Type] => text/html
)
```

So you can access specific header.